# Scrapy: How to extract data from a page that loads it via ajax?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract data from a search result that is partially build via ajax:

https://www.vitalsana.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=ibuprofen

The wanted data `PZN: 16336937` is somehow injected after page onload:

xpath does return an empty result:

```
//[@id="maincontent"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/ol/li[1]/form/div/div[2]/p[2]/span[2]/span
```

Sanme goes for the data `verfügbar`. It is loaded after pageload via this API I guess:
https://www.vitalsana.com/catalogsearch/searchTermsLog/save/?q=ibuprofen

I noticed that some info is within inline JS, but it is difficult to get just this JS. I tried last, but this seems to be ignored. It gets all JS including the desired info:

```
response.xpath('//script[last()]/text()').extract()
```

I am using scrapy 2.1.0. Is there a way to retrieve this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PZN: 16336937` is not present in the search results (Vitamin D3 != Ibuprofen).

To get the PZN number of a product (8 digits), you can extract it from the img element of each product. For example, for the first search result (`[1]`) :

```
response.xpath('substring(substring-before((//img[@class="product-image-photo img-fluid"])[1]/@src,"_"),string-length(substring-before((//img[@class="product-image-photo img-fluid"])[1]/@src,"_"))-7,8)').extract()
```

Output : `07728561`

You could also extract the value directly from the script element, but you'll have to figure out how to escape single quotes in scrapy. The XPath :

```
substring-after(substring-before(//script[contains(.,"Suche")],'",'),'"id": "')
```

Output : `07728561`

Note : using regex instead of substring functions might be cleaner.

What you could try also is to "rebuild" the json from the script element, load the json, then query on it. Something like this should work :

```
import json

products = response.xpath('substring(substring-after(//script[contains(.,"Suche")],"] ="),1,string-length(substring-after(//script[contains(.,"Suche")],"] ="))-1)').extract()

result = json.loads(products)
for i in result:
    print i['id']
```

Last option : request directly the data from the API (with a well-formed payload, a valid token and the appropiate method).

Comment: Thank you. I went with a similar solution like you explained in option 1 to get the PZN. This seems to work for some PZNs, but not all (e.g. the ones with a dummy image), but the main problem is, that I can not get the mentioned and needed availability info. So far I could not find this info within the HTML that I could parse.

Comment: Since the display of availability of products is javascript related, I think your best option is to use Selenium for your project or other similar tools.